# Can't Open File in Pycharm using Openpyxl

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I'm trying to open an Excel file using Pycharm, but always get a the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Excelmodules/openxlsx.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openpyxl import openpyxl
ImportError: cannot import name 'openpyxl' from 'openpyxl' (C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Excelmodules\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py)`


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have successfully installed `Openpyxl` in Pycharm (using another thread on stackoverflow) and have checked the file name/path is correct, but still get the error message.

I am new to python so it might be something I have/haven't done, but the only things I can think are causing this are:

1. running it through Pycharm rather than command prompt
2. Windows 10 did a forced update and created an "old windows folder and I'm wondering whether Pycharm or openpyxl are trying use/run using the old.windows folder
3. the Excel file needs to be in the Pycharm folder

I was starting a project in Automate the Boring stuff, but can't get past this step.

Please help!

Thank you
Rob

Comment: change `from openpyxl import openpyxl` to `import openpyxl`

Comment: openpyxl is installed on a python environment (not pycharm). Could you please post the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I have tried your suggestion but I get a longer list of error messages

Comment: Hi, the code is:from openpyxl import openpyxl

wb: Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\ Users\ ITadmin\ Desktop\ PythonExcelModuleTestFile.xlsx")
type(wb)

Comment: C:\Users\ITadmin\PycharmProjects\Excelmodules\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/ITadmin/PycharmProjects/Excelmodules/openxlsx.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ITadmin/PycharmProjects/Excelmodules/openxlsx.py", line 4, in <module>

Comment: wb: Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\ Users\ ITadmin\ Desktop\ PythonExcelModuleTestFile.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\ITadmin\PycharmProjects\Excelmodules\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\ITadmin\PycharmProjects\Excelmodules\venv\lib\site-

Comment: packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\ITadmin\PycharmProjects\Excelmodules\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\ITadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1250, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\ Users\\ ITadmin\\ Desktop\\ PythonExcelModuleTestFile.xlsx'
Process finished with exit code 1